# Why does this crossword puzzle generator not actually insert any words into the grid?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a program to generate sparse crossword/anagram puzzles that should look like this:

```
-------------T--
-----------OGRE-
---------T---O--
--------FORGET--
---------R------
---------T------
```

In this case, the words are `FORGET`, `OGRE`, `TORT`, and `TROT`. The rules for the grid's design are roughly what you'd expect; words have to intersect on the same letter, words can't run adjacent to each other, and all the words supplied have to share a subset of some set of letters. They're anagrams.

The code below implements the grid, and a method to "scan" the grid and insert each word at the first valid position. The first word is inserted at the approximate center of the puzzle.

Unfortunately, the code doesn't actually insert anything beyond the first word, and for the life of me I can't figure out what is wrong with my checks in the `word_fits` function.

```
import enum
import io
import itertools
import math
import random


@enum.unique
class Direction(enum.Enum):
    ACROSS, DOWN = enum.auto(), enum.auto()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_deltas(self):
        return int(self == Direction.DOWN),  int(self == Direction.ACROSS)

    @staticmethod
    def random():
        return random.choice(list(Direction))


class Grid:
    def __init__(self, height = 16, width = 16):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.grid = {r: {c: [] for c in range(width)} for r in range(height)}
        self.num_words = 0

    def get_letter(self, r, c):
        if not self.grid[r][c]:
            return []
        letters = {word[offset] for (word, offset, _) in self.grid[r][c]}
        assert(len(letters) == 1)
        return letters.pop()

    def get_words(self, r, c):
        if not self.grid[r][c]:
            return []
        return [word for word, _, _ in self.grid[r][c]]

    def approximate_center(self):
        return math.floor(self.height/ 2), math.floor(self.width/ 2)

    def word_fits(self, word, r, c, direction):
        # Make sure we aren't inserting the word outside the grid
        if ((direction == Direction.DOWN and r + len(word) >= self.height) or (direction == Direction.ACROSS and c + len(word) >= self.width)):
            return False

        # Otherwise we get a KeyError (for being out of bounds) when we check
        # the adjacent cells later in this function
        if r == 0 or c == 0 or r == self.height-1 or c == self.width-1:
            return False

        delta_r, delta_c = direction.get_deltas()

        # Check that the word doesn't overlap any letters incorrectly
        intersects = False
        for offset, letter in enumerate(word):
            rr = r + offset*delta_r
            cc = c + offset*delta_c
            other_letter = self.get_letter(rr, cc)
            if other_letter:
                if letter != other_letter: return False
                else: intersects = True

            # Check adjacent cells
            for delta in [-1, 1]:
                rr = r + offset*delta_r + delta*delta_c
                cc = c + offset*delta_c + delta*delta_r
                if self.grid[rr][cc]:
                    if any(direction == d for _, _, d in self.grid[rr][cc]):
                        return False
#                    if set(self.get_words(r+offset*delta_r, c+offset*delta_c)) & set(self.get_words(rr, cc)):
#                        return False

                if offset == 0:
                    # delta == -1
                    # point directly to the left (above) a word placed across (down)
                    #
                    # delta == 1
                    # point directly to the right (below) a word placed across (down)

                    if delta == -1:
                        rr = r + delta*delta_r
                        cc = c + delta*delta_c
                    elif delta == 1:
                        rr = r + delta*len(word)*delta_r
                        cc = c + delta*len(word)*delta_c

                    if self.grid[rr][cc]:
                        if any(direction == d for _, _, d in self.grid[rr][cc]):
                            return False

        return True and intersects

    def insert_word(self, word, r, c, direction):
        assert(isinstance(direction, Direction))
        delta_r, delta_c = direction.get_deltas()
        for offset, _ in enumerate(word):
           self.grid[r + offset*delta_r][c + offset*delta_c].append((word.upper(), offset, direction))
        self.num_words += 1


    def scan_and_insert_word(self, word):
        if self.num_words == 0:
            self.insert_word(word, *self.approximate_center(), Direction.random())
            return
        for d, r, c in itertools.product(list(Direction), range(self.height), range(self.width)):
            if self.word_fits(word, r, c, d):
                self.insert_word(word, r, c, d)
                break
        raise ValueError(f""""{word}" could not be inserted.""")

    def __str__(self):
        output = io.StringIO()
        for r in range(self.height):
            for c in range(self.width):
                if self.grid[r][c]:
                    # Checks elsewhere ensure that there are no inconsistencies
                    # in the letters specified by each (word, offset, direction)
                    # triplet, so we can just grab the first one
                    word, offset, _ = self.grid[r][c][0]
                    letter = word[offset]
                else:
                    letter = "-"
                output.write(letter)
            output.write("\n")
        contents = output.getvalue()
        output.close()
        return contents


random.seed(1)
word_list = ["FORGET", "TROT", "OGRE", "TORT"]
g = Grid()
for word in word_list:
    g.scan_and_insert_word(word.upper())
    print(g)
```

There are a lot of checks that still need to be implemented in this code, e.g. checking that the words all share the same say of `N` letters, for some `N`, but I'm trying to figure out this bug before moving on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `scan_and_insert_word` function:

The first word is inserted with no issues because if `self.num_words == 0`, you insert the word in the center (approximately) and terminate the function (GOOD).

If that is not true, you try to find a place in the grid where the word can fit. Once a suitable position is found, you insert the word and `break` (instead of `return`, which would terminate the function prematurely). Since you are `break`ing instead of `return`ing, all you're doing is breaking out of the loop, and then raising the `ValueError` exception even though you've found a perfectly valid spot for the new word.

The fix:

Change the `break` to a `return`. Or do this:

```
def scan_and_insert_word(self, word):
    if self.num_words == 0:
        self.insert_word(word, *self.approximate_center(), Direction.random())
        return
    for d, r, c in itertools.product(list(Direction), range(self.height), range(self.width)):
        if self.word_fits(word, r, c, d):
            self.insert_word(word, r, c, d)
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError(f""""{word}" could not be inserted.""")
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a silly mistake on my part. Fixing that bug does result in words being inserted now, although it does so incorrectly. That should be another question though. (To be clear, what I mean is that the first letters of `TORT` and `OGRE` are now next to each other when by the rules, they shouldn't be touching)

Comment: Ah yes, I see that too. I'll take another look. Also, I just want to say thanks for asking your question is such a straightforward way - it's always more fun to help troubleshoot when a question has been formulated well, and if the problem is interesting, too!

Comment: I think the new bug is a separate issue, so I posted a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58824998/2766558) that just focuses on that bug.

Comment: Ah. The thread you linked to doesn't exist anymore. Did you end up solving the issue?

Comment: Oh, no, I deleted it when people voted to close it. I think I need to invest more time in writing a smaller minimal working example.